# How to run cURL via guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

First time using cURL and guzzle. This is probably a simple question but would appreciate a "helloworld" example.

This is the cURL I currently have:

```
curl --include --request POST \
--header "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--header "X-Access-Token: ACCESS_TOKEN" \
--data-binary "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=PUBLIC_KEY&client_secret=PRIVATE_KEY" \
'https://api.url.com/token'
```

And this is the guzzle code:

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$result = $client->post('https://api.url.com/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'sample-form-data' => 'value'
    ]
]);
```

I'm not sure how to run the cURL command using guzzle. How would the resulting guzzle code look like?

Comment: This should already send a POST request. Given you have `ext_curl` enabled in PHP it would even prefer to use cURL. What is the problem?

Comment: In the options-array you pass you can also put a `headers` key to pass the Auth/Token header. See http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

Comment: How would I write the above cURL code using guzzle? What would the resulting php code look like?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make the question clearer. If it's unclear I apologize. I'm basically asking how can I run the cURL in php. I'm new to cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the answer for converting cURL to Guzzle. Maybe it will help future people that need a "helloworld" like I did. This is how I ran the cURL in PHP via Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();
$uri = 'https://api.url.com/token';
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Access-Token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN
];
$body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='.$PUBLIC_KEY.'&client_secret='.$PRIVATE_KEY;
$result = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => $body
]);

json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Two things that weren't intuitive was you have to designate 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as Content-Type. And 'data-binary' as 'body'.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer, I see you already found [a solution yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243492/7362396). While it works, it's not the Guzzle way / "best practise" to manually code your body payload like that.

Guzzle provides a cleaner way for that, and builds the body-payload internally:

```
$result = $client->post('https://api.url.com/token', [
  'headers' => ['X-Access-Token' => 'ACCESS_TOKEN'],
  'form_params' => [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => 'PUBLIC_KEY',
    'client_secret' => 'PRIVATE_KEY',
  ],
]);
```

Correct concatenation with `?`/`&` aswell as adding the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is done by Guzzle automatically. This is the request that is sent off by the above code:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 76
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.57.0 PHP/7.2.2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.url.com
X-Access-Token: ACCESS_TOKEN

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=PUBLIC_KEY&client_secret=PRIVATE_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get/see the result of your Guzzle call by calling the "getBody" function.  In your case, $result->getBody()

Comment: Maybe my question is not very clear? If so I apologize. Basically I'm trying to figure out how can I run the cURL command using php. It's my first time using cURL from php.